# Strange physics effect on self-created SCNGeometry

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to build a pool game, downloaded a 3D model(.blend) from [sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/snooker-table-b5930e8c780a4eabaad4e3e9be23ef09), and exported it as .dae file, then I drag it into Xcode and converted to .scn file.

When I finish the coding part and add the collision effect that make the balls run through the 'table', everything went perfect except this strange physics effect: the ball will jump slightly as it passes through the middle of the 'table', when I turn on the 'Physics' in the scene graph, it is clear to see there are some lines in the middle area that generate the little jump. And it looks like there are some wrinkles in that part but not appear in Blender. Why is this happen and how to solve it?

[image]

[image: without 'Physics' line]

[image: with 'Physics' line]

[image: raw file in Blender]

I checked the single 'table' in raw file(.blend) and find nothing in the physics property

[image: physics property]

Comment: what type of static physics body did you give to the table? it might be also a bug within the geometry itself. A workaround could be to remove the physics from the table and add instead an invisible SCNBox with like: x=5m, y=0.05m z=2m. Use concave Polihedron for the physics body.

Comment: @ZAY Thanks for your reply. Since I need this irregular geometry to let the ball fall into the pocket, so it has to be SCNGeometry instead of any specific geometry. And the table you can imagine is a box that cut off some part...I can understand what you advice is to turn off the physics property of the table and add some invisible box under the table, is that right? seems that it would work but just little annoying to put lot of small box to approximate that curve (sounds like calculus)

Comment: @ZAY I suddenly found where the wrinkles come from: If I add a modifier 'triangulate' to the table in Blender, the wireframe would be that same in the Xcode, So I guess the reason is Xcode automatically use this 'triangulate' effect when it convert the model from .dae file to .scn file, or open any .dae file it will use 'triangulate'...BUT knowing this does not help me get rid of the unnecessary  wireframe....

Comment: I mean, what if you construct that invisible table in blender, but instead of the round holes, you have squares as holes? this would reduce the entire geomertry a lot. I often use such smaller, invisible geometries instead of the high-poly visible geometry. It might also improve the entire performence. But it is just an idea.

Comment: Let me have a try, thank you very very much!